# why "resize" event not working for my function to detect the height?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table with `div`s, and I want to each row get the biggest cell height. I have written a function to get it. On first load the function works properly, but when resizing the window, the function is not working. Can you tell me what's the problem?

```js
const setHeight = function() {
  let hieghts = []
  let classes = 1
  let rowNum = document.querySelector("#desc").childElementCount
  for (classes; classes < rowNum; classes++) {
    document.querySelectorAll(`.content${classes}`).forEach(td => {
      hieghts.push(td.clientHeight)
    })
    let max = Math.max(...hieghts)
    document.querySelectorAll(`.content${classes}`).forEach(td => {
      td.style.height = `${max}px`
    })
    max = 0
    hieghts = []
  }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", setHeight) // why this line not working?
setHeight();
```

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.cells {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">code title 1</span>
    <span class="cells content1">dev-1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">dev-2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">dev-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">code </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="desc" class="col">
    <span class="cells content title">description</span>
    <span class="cells content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit  </span>
    <span class="cells content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore  </span>
    <span class="cells content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">num</span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">1</span>
    <span class="cells content3">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">prise</span>
    <span class="cells content1">100</span>
    <span class="cells content2">200</span>
    <span class="cells content3">300</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">total </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1000</span>
    <span class="cells content2">20000</span>
    <span class="cells content3">15000</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use CSS to make your design responsive?

Comment: i want the vertical lines even when the rows are not enough to fill the table. have an idea for it with css only?

Comment: The "resize" event listener works properly in your code. It's your setHeight function that is not working properly. I'll check what I can do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off using a table would be much easier to control the height of the rows but Ill give you what you asked for. The main issue with your JavaScript is that you never clear the style on the rows so once the inital function runs they will always be the same. In order to achieve what you want you need to.

1. Select all the cells
2. Create a variable to store the biggest cell
3. Loop over the cells and first clear their inline styles
4. Run a conditional to see if the current cell is bigger than the biggest cell variable. If it is store that height as your new biggestCell value.
5. Once all the cells are checked loop over the cells again and set the height to the biggestCell value.
6. I also added a short debounce function (2 seconds) in order to keep your function from running every second the window is being resized.

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 200){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}

const checkHeight = function() {
  console.log("resize running...")
  const cells = document.querySelectorAll(".cells");
  let biggestCell = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < cells.length; index++) {
    const cell = cells[index];
    cell.style.height = "";
    if (cell.getBoundingClientRect().height > biggestCell) {
      biggestCell = cell.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    }
  }
  for (let index = 0; index < cells.length; index++) {
    const cell = cells[index];
    cell.style.height = biggestCell + "px";
  }
}
window.addEventListener("resize", debounce(() => checkHeight()));
checkHeight();
```

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.cells {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">code title 1</span>
    <span class="cells content1">dev-1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">dev-2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">dev-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">code </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="desc" class="col">
    <span class="cells content title">description</span>
    <span class="cells content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit  </span>
    <span class="cells content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore  </span>
    <span class="cells content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">num</span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">1</span>
    <span class="cells content3">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">prise</span>
    <span class="cells content1">100</span>
    <span class="cells content2">200</span>
    <span class="cells content3">300</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">total </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1000</span>
    <span class="cells content2">20000</span>
    <span class="cells content3">15000</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The resize event is fired literally hundreds of times while the window is being resized (don't believe me? place a `console.log('fired')` in checkHeight function). Instead, it should be fired only once, after the user has finished resizing the window. You can accomplish this with a `setTimeout`/`clearTimeout`.

Comment: I believe you @JoseRuiSantos I would defiantly add in a debounce function in a production ready application. I know its not perfect but my answer was focused only on how to get the functionality in the window resize to work.

Comment: I have added a debounce function @JoseRuiSantos

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you calculate the `max` value in a single for loop and try to set the row height in the table in the same loop. In this case, the row height retains its current state. You will see this logic error if you print the `max` value to the console in the old method; The height of all rows in the table is printed to the console, not the maximum value.

```js
let rowNum = document.querySelector("#desc").childElementCount;

const setHeight = function() {
    let heights = [];

    /* All row heights are placed in the array. */
    for(let index = 1 ; index < rowNum ; ++index)
    {
        document.querySelectorAll(`.content${index}`).forEach(td => {
            heights.push(td.clientHeight)
        });
    }
    
    /* Maximum row height is learned. */
    let max = Math.max(...heights);
    console.log(max);
    
    /* The maximum row height is assigned to all rows in the table. */    
    for(let index = 1 ; index < rowNum ; ++index)
    {
        document.querySelectorAll(`.content${index}`).forEach(td => {
            td.style.height = `${max}px`
        });
    }
}

window.addEventListener("resize", setHeight);
setHeight();
```

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  height: 90vh;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.cells {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">code title 1</span>
    <span class="cells content1">dev-1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">dev-2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">dev-3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">code </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">2</span>
    <span class="cells content3">3</span>
  </div>
  <div id="desc" class="col">
    <span class="cells content title">description</span>
    <span class="cells content1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit  </span>
    <span class="cells content2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore  </span>
    <span class="cells content3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis incidunt inventore  </span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">num</span>
    <span class="cells content1">1</span>
    <span class="cells content2">1</span>
    <span class="cells content3">1</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">prise</span>
    <span class="cells content1">100</span>
    <span class="cells content2">200</span>
    <span class="cells content3">300</span>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <span class="cells title">total </span>
    <span class="cells content1">1000</span>
    <span class="cells content2">20000</span>
    <span class="cells content3">15000</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's not work for me...